# Silverlight RadGridView search as you type fails when used Custom GridViewColumn

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radgridview

I am trying to implement [Search as you type](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GridView/Search) feature of telerik's RadGridView Silverlight control.

It is working properly if I have simple `GridViewDataColumn` in the GridView. But if grid has columns other than it it fails.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public CustomFilterDescriptor(IEnumerable<Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn> columns)
        {
            this.compositeFilterDesriptor = new CompositeFilterDescriptor();
            this.compositeFilterDesriptor.LogicalOperator = FilterCompositionLogicalOperator.Or;
            try
            {//tHIS throws the error

                ***foreach (GridViewDataColumn column in columns)
                {
                    this.compositeFilterDesriptor.FilterDescriptors.Add(this.CreateFilterForColumn(column));
                }
            }***
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

How can I skip the column which are not GridViewDataColumn ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be very simple.If someone runs in to similar problem here is modified code.

```
foreach (var column in columns)
                {
                    if (column.GetType() == typeof(GridViewDataColumn))
                    {
                        this.compositeFilterDesriptor.FilterDescriptors.Add(this.CreateFilterForColumn(column as GridViewDataColumn));
                    }
                }
```